# How Convert Python UDP Packet to C#

Tags: c#, python, networking, byte

I am currently trying to turn on my Xbox using a simple script that I found on GitHub, what it does is send a raw packet to the desired EndPoint and the Xbox turns on, I am having trouble converting the script from python into a C# script and would appreciate any support on the matter, here is a snippet of the python script:

```
class xbox_functions:

def __init__(self, live_id, xbox_addr):
    self.live_id = live_id
    self.xbox_addr = xbox_addr
    self.xbox_port = 5050
    self.xbox_ping = "dd00000a000000000000000400000002"

def turn_on_xbox(self, times=5):
    i = "xbox id code"
    live_id = i.encode("utf-8")
    power_payload = b'\x00' + chr(len(live_id)).encode() + live_id + b'\x00'
    power_header = b'\xdd\x02\x00' + chr(len(power_payload)).encode() + b'\x00\x00'
    power_packet = power_header + power_payload
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.bind(("", 0))
    s.connect(("ip address", 5050))

    for inc in range(times):
        s.send(power_packet)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have been able to translate so far?

Comment: That's the issue, I have not been successful in translating the code so I have no idea if what I have translated so far will be relevant.

Comment: @ILop78ILop78 The idea is to see what C# code you have so far and advise which parts need fixing & how.